# What are common use cases for git fetch?

Tags: git, version-control, fetch

I'm learning Git, and helping some co-workers get up to speed with it. So far, I haven't found a good reason to use `git fetch`. It just doesn't seem to have a lot of utility compared to using `git pull` or even `git pull --rebase` judiciously.

I discussed this question with a co-worker, and he came up with some relatively narrow and contrived situations where a `git fetch` would be used independently in a workflow, but I'm still not really convinced (eg updating branches that do not have a set upstream source, requiring updates to local repos without conflicts before commiting).

Are there any good use cases for using `git fetch` regularly?

Comment: git fetch doesn't do the auto merges like the git pull does so in a sense its regarded as safe. Coz when you have uncommitted changes.

Comment: Personally, I never use `git pull`... I prefer to always `git fetch`, review what I would be merging, and then run `git merge` myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use it when it just want to know whether there are new changes.

Another use case is `git fetch -t`, which is necessary if tags have been moved (IMHO not a good idea).

Answer (score 3):

I use it all the time, specifically when I want to update *some aspect* of my local repo's view of an upstream repo, without touching my working copy:

1. just to fetch tags (say when someone else added a release tag)
2. to fetch a new remote branch I wasn't using before (maybe to start tracking a feature branch created by someone else)
3. just to update `origin/master` without affecting `master`

As for *why* I may care about `pull` touching my working copy, it's likely because:

1. I have uncommitted changes on my current branch which I don't want to commit yet
2. ... and don't want to stash them just for this
3. I care about the current HEAD or working tree state (maybe I have a build running in the background, and can't have `pull` updating source files under it)